# break a user inputted sentence in c using strtok and put the sentences in a 2d array

Tags: c

Hello I am trying to break up a series of strings by spaces in a sentence and display it line by line via a 2d array but am only getting the first word inputted in a sentence. I am using strtok_r but seem to find what I'm doing wrong.
    int split(char *s)

```
{   
int count=0;


printf("the code is here");
char *rest;


char* token=strtok_r(s," ", &rest);


while(token != NULL){
    count++;
    printf("token \s\n ", token);
    token=strtok_r(NULL," ",&rest);

    if(count==0){
        printf("problem \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

     char ** twod=(char**)calloc((count+1),sizeof(char*));
     token=strtok_r(s," ",&rest);
     int x=0;
     while(token !=NULL){
        twod[x]=(char*)calloc(strlen(token+1),sizeof(char));
        strcpy(twod[x],token);
        x++;
        token=strtok_r(NULL," ", &rest);
        for(x=0;x<count;x++){
            printf("%s  ", twod[x]);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debugit

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `printf("token \s\n ", token);`  the `\s` is an escape sequence, not a 'output format conversion specifier`.  Suggest: `printf("token %s\n ", token);`

Comment: regarding: `while(token != NULL){
    count++;
    ...
    if(count==0){`   the variable `count` was initialized to 0 then incremented on each pass through the `while()` loop, so it can NEVER be ==0

Comment: regarding: `char ** twod=(char**)calloc((count+1),sizeof(char*));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  All the cast does is clutter the code.  Suggest removing that cast

Comment: regarding: `twod[x]=(char*)calloc(strlen(token+1),sizeof(char));
        strcpy(twod[x],token);`  Strongly suggest learning about the `strdup()` function  And this expression: `strlen(token+1)` will be too short.  suggest: `strlen( token ) +1`

Comment: regarding: `for(x=0;x<count;x++){
            printf("%s  ", twod[x]);
        }`  Suggest this code be moved to after the end of that last `while()` loop so only output the saved parts once rather than after every extracted substring.  Also, the posted code does not places the first two extracted sub strings into the array,  Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: the last `while()` loop never extends the length of the allocated memory for: `twod` so after a couple of sub strings, the code will be trying to write past the end of the array.  The result is undefined behavior and can result in a seg fault event

Comment: the function signature `int split( char* )` states that there will be an integer returned value, but the posted code does not contain a `return` statement much less a return statement with a value

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. is missing the `main()` function
2. corrects the signature for function: `split()`
3. documents why each header file is included
4. performs the desired functionality
5. cleanly compiles, except maybe on windows
6. does not use the function: `strtok_r()`
7. If compiled on Windows, will need a statement at the top of the code similar to: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1`
8. places all the extracted strings into the 2 dimensional array, rather than skipping the first 2
9. expands the amount of memory for `twod[]`, as needed, so as to avoid undefined behavior
10. checks for errors and handles them properly, including freeing the allocated memory before exiting.  Checks for errors from `realloc()` and `strdup()`
11. frees the allocated memory before exiting, so as to avoid any memory leaks
12. Note: it is ok to pass NULL to `free()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <string.h>   // strdup(), strtok()
#include <stdlib.h>   // realloc(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, free()
#include <stdio.h>    // printf(), perror()

void split( char *s )
{   
    size_t  count=0;
    char ** twod = NULL;

    char*   token = strtok( s, " " );

    while( token )
    {
        count++;
        printf("token %s\n ", token);        

        char ** temp = realloc( twod, count * sizeof( char * ) );
        if( ! temp )
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            for( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                free( twod[i] );
            }
            free( twod );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        twod = temp;

        twod[ count -1 ] = strdup( token );
        if( ! twod[ count -1 ] )
        {
            perror( "strdup failed" );
            for( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                free( twod[i] );
            }
            free( twod );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        token = strtok( NULL," " );
    }

    for( size_t x=0; x < count; x++ )
    {
        printf("%s  ", twod[x]);
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        free( twod[i] );
    }
    free( twod );
}
```